# How to do location based search in web app with own locations database

Tags: database, google-places-api

I want to implement location based search (i.e. Location + radius) on my website. The locations will be added to my database. I thought I would use Google Places API, but I cannot find how to make it work with own locations database. Is it possible at all? I would appreciate an example or a link to some tutorial.  If not is there any other solution that could do the trick? Please keep in mind I cannot install anything to the server, so adding some geo extension to DB is not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google [**Geocoding**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) service to find the coordinates of your location . You can then use these coordinates to find locations in your database.
If you have PHP/MySQL on your server the code below uses the [**Haversine formaula**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) using [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, (6372 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM mytable HAVING distance < 1 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);//Coordinates of location
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);//Coordinates of location
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
```

Where 6372 if using kms and 3959 for miles

This query was used in this [**DEMO**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php)